# specific packages in a external jar GWT

Tags: gwt

i have a jar file with many packages, 
Out of which i need only a few in the Client Side GWT code, but i need this whole jar in my server side.

And as of now this jar doesn't have  an xml file.

this is the jar structure ,

```
source.package1
source.package2
...
```

So here if i put a xml file in source folder with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<source path='package1'></source>
<source path='package2'></source>
</module>
```

for only those packages needed and inherit this in my project xml, will it work?

The reason for not including all the packages is, it is not GWT compatible. But the ones i am including are.

Answer (score 0):

In general this will work, but you have to have .java file and not .class files for GWT to work on. So including the sources of that your (or just the two packages) is also required.

Since you seem to control the build of the other jar file you might want to build a specific gwt jar file that contains your gwt.xml and the .java files for those two packages.

Comment: For the first part of your answer, Do i need to have the .java file, As the way i see it.. I dont think we need to have the source file, because i am now using sencha libraries jar files which has only the class files and even gwt visualization jar has only the class files. But i am not sure if its the case. Say if i need to have the source files as well then why i need a jar then ? For the second part, yes i control the build of the jar. But having 2 separate jar files for server and client doesn't serve the purpose it is just a redundant codes.

Comment: GWT __always__ requires .java files. With sencha those are located inside the jar as well.

Comment: Ok i created the jar with .class & .java files. I have this on my projectgwt.xml `<inherits name="jarpackage.xmlname" />` the xml filename is without `.gwt.xml` extension here. And the xml file  has ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module>
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
 <source path='package1'/>
 <source path='package2'/>
</module> ` When i compile it no error. I use these classes on server side no problem. But when i try to use it on client it gives me **No Class found exception** with same old **did you forget to inherit something** error. what am i doing wrong here ?